# Search for a specific item in an array of objects and query if an attribute exists

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Sample data:

```
{
  _id: '1234',
  games: [{
    name: 'World of Warcraft',
    lastLogin: ISODate(),
    subscriptions: ['56', '78']
  }, {
    name: 'Starcraft II',
    lastLogin: ISODate()
  }]
}
```

Essentially, I want to find everyone that does not have a "subscriptions" field for a given game. I can't quite figure out a good way to do it.

```
Players.update({
  'games.name': 'World of Warcraft',
  'games.$.subscriptions': { $exists: false }
}, {
  $set: { 'games.$.subscriptions': GLOBAL_SUB }
});
```

How do you query an array of elements for an attribute and the existence of a field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch) when you want to match multiple terms on the same array element:

```
Players.update({
    games: { $elemMatch: {
        name: 'World of Warcraft',
        subscriptions: { $exists: false }
    }}
}, {
    $set: { 'games.$.subscriptions': GLOBAL_SUB }
});
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you sir